# How i can add content in .txt with operators like < in a .txt with powershell? Use a delimiter to treat text?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add content in a txt file with the add-content command but within the text I have things like several "",,[], commands that I don't want powershell to run but I can't get powershell to identify all as text.
My question, could you add some kind of delimiter as in MySQL that indicates that it treats everything inside as text?

Comment: You can escape those characters with backticks.

Comment: Have you put quotes around the text?

Comment: did yoiu try surrounding the string with single-quotes `'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent PS interpreting that characters, you must to use bacticks before the character (e.g.: `[, `\, `"). Do not confuse with apostrophe (')

Comment: Thanks gui, i will try later ;)